# Displaying values in a MySQL database into a calendar

Tags: php, html, sql, calendar

I currently have a MySQL database with reservations in it. It has ArrivalDate and DepartureDate. I am looking for a way to have it display the names from each reservation into a calendar, under all the days during their stay so it can be easily viewed. At least an outline on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Currently I have the following to calculate all the days they are staying:

```
$period = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime($row['ArrivalDate']),
    DateInterval::createFromDateString('+1 day'),
    new DateTime($row['DepartureDate'])
);                    
foreach ( $period as $dt ) {
    echo $dt->format( 'd-m-Y' ) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: What is your desired output? View by month? All reservations on a single view?

Comment: My desired output would be a monthly calendar yes, with the reservations displaying under their respective dates. (Just display last name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initial sample data:

```
+----+------------+-------------+---------------+
| id | name       | arrivalDate | departureDate |
+----+------------+-------------+---------------+
|  1 | John Smith | 2020-07-17  | 2020-07-20    |
|  2 | John Doe   | 2020-07-18  | 2020-07-22    |
|  3 | Jack Smith | 2020-07-28  | 2020-08-02    |
+----+------------+-------------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

The outline is: you probably can do it in a single sql query per month to get the data you need, but i followed different approach.
In php get the month you want to display (current if not provided). Calculate first day and last day of that month - make a period of it. For each day in the period fetch reservations that are valid for that day. Now you have all the days in the month with all reservations for each day and you can display it however you want. Also calculate previous and next month and display this info so you can browse next/previous month.

I did it as a script that accepts a month as parameter, if no parameter is provided it displays current month.

```
<?php

// database and query
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=calendar", 'z', 'z');

function selectFromDate(DateTime $date): array {
  global $db;

  $q = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE arrivalDate <= :date AND departureDate >= :date");
  $q->execute([':date' => $date->format('Y-m-d')]);

  return $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}

// initial dates
$yearMonthDate = new DateTime();
if ($argc > 1) {
  $yearMonthDate = new DateTime($argv[1]);
}
$yearMonth = $yearMonthDate->format('Y-m');
$nextYearMonth = (clone $yearMonthDate)->modify('first day of next month')->format('Y-m');
$previousYearMonth = (clone $yearMonthDate)->modify('first day of previous month')->format('Y-m');
$firstDayDate = (clone $yearMonthDate)->modify('first day of this month');
$lastDayDate = (clone $yearMonthDate)->modify('last day of this month');
$monthPeriod = new DatePeriod($firstDayDate, new DateInterval('P1D'), $lastDayDate);

// fetch data
$monthData = [];
foreach ($monthPeriod as $date) {
  $dayInfo = new stdClass();
  $dayInfo->date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
  $dayInfo->reservations = [];

  foreach (selectFromDate($date) as $reservation) {
    $dayInfo->reservations[] = $reservation->name;
  }
  $monthData[] = $dayInfo;
}
var_dump($monthData);

// display
echo 'Displaying: '.$yearMonth.PHP_EOL;
foreach ($monthData as $day) {
  echo '  '.$day->date.': '.join($day->reservations, ', ');
  echo PHP_EOL;
}

echo 'Previous month: '.$previousYearMonth. ', next month: '.$nextYearMonth.PHP_EOL;
```

You call it like this: `file.php` and get output like this (no parameter - output for current month):

```
Displaying: 2020-07
  2020-07-01: 
  2020-07-02: 
  2020-07-03: 
  2020-07-04: 
  2020-07-05: 
  2020-07-06: 
  2020-07-07: 
  2020-07-08: 
  2020-07-09: 
  2020-07-10: 
  2020-07-11: 
  2020-07-12: 
  2020-07-13: 
  2020-07-14: 
  2020-07-15: 
  2020-07-16: 
  2020-07-17: John Smith
  2020-07-18: John Smith, John Doe
  2020-07-19: John Smith, John Doe
  2020-07-20: John Smith, John Doe
  2020-07-21: John Doe
  2020-07-22: John Doe
  2020-07-23: 
  2020-07-24: 
  2020-07-25: 
  2020-07-26: 
  2020-07-27: 
  2020-07-28: Jack Smith
  2020-07-29: Jack Smith
  2020-07-30: Jack Smith
Previous month: 2020-06, next month: 2020-08
```

Contents of `$monthData`:

```
array(30) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#8 (2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2020-07-01"
    ["reservations"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#7 (2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2020-07-02"
    ["reservations"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#9 (2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2020-07-03"
    ["reservations"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [3]=>
  object(stdClass)#10 (2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2020-07-04"
    ["reservations"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [4]=>
  object(stdClass)#11 (2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2020-07-05"
    ["reservations"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [5]=>
  object(stdClass)#12 (2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2020-07-06"
    ["reservations"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [6]=>
  object(stdClass)#13 (2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2020-07-07"
    ["reservations"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [7]=>
  object(stdClass)#14 (2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2020-07-08"
    ["reservations"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [8]=>
  object(stdClass)#15 (2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2020-07-09"
    ["reservations"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [9]=>
  object(stdClass)#16 (2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2020-07-10"
    ["reservations"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [10]=>
  object(stdClass)#17 (2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2020-07-11"
    ["reservations"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [11]=>
  object(stdClass)#18 (2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2020-07-12"
    ["reservations"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [12]=>
  object(stdClass)#19 (2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2020-07-13"
    ["reservations"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [13]=>
  object(stdClass)#20 (2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2020-07-14"
    ["reservations"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [14]=>
  object(stdClass)#21 (2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2020-07-15"
    ["reservations"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [15]=>
  object(stdClass)#22 (2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2020-07-16"
    ["reservations"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [16]=>
  object(stdClass)#23 (2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2020-07-17"
    ["reservations"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "John Smith"
    }
  }
  [17]=>
  object(stdClass)#24 (2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2020-07-18"
    ["reservations"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "John Smith"
      [1]=>
      string(8) "John Doe"
    }
  }
  [18]=>
  object(stdClass)#25 (2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2020-07-19"
    ["reservations"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "John Smith"
      [1]=>
      string(8) "John Doe"
    }
  }
  [19]=>
  object(stdClass)#28 (2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2020-07-20"
    ["reservations"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "John Smith"
      [1]=>
      string(8) "John Doe"
    }
  }
  [20]=>
  object(stdClass)#27 (2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2020-07-21"
    ["reservations"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "John Doe"
    }
  }
  [21]=>
  object(stdClass)#26 (2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2020-07-22"
    ["reservations"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "John Doe"
    }
  }
  [22]=>
  object(stdClass)#31 (2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2020-07-23"
    ["reservations"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [23]=>
  object(stdClass)#29 (2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2020-07-24"
    ["reservations"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [24]=>
  object(stdClass)#30 (2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2020-07-25"
    ["reservations"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [25]=>
  object(stdClass)#33 (2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2020-07-26"
    ["reservations"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [26]=>
  object(stdClass)#34 (2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2020-07-27"
    ["reservations"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [27]=>
  object(stdClass)#35 (2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2020-07-28"
    ["reservations"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "Jack Smith"
    }
  }
  [28]=>
  object(stdClass)#36 (2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2020-07-29"
    ["reservations"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "Jack Smith"
    }
  }
  [29]=>
  object(stdClass)#32 (2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2020-07-30"
    ["reservations"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "Jack Smith"
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see it is an array with 30 elements (one for each day in the month). Each element contains a date and reservations for this day so now it is easy to display this as you see fit (html for example).

If you want to see next month call it like this: `file.php 2020-08` and you will get this output:

```
Displaying: 2020-08
  2020-08-01: Jack Smith
  2020-08-02: Jack Smith
  2020-08-03: 
  2020-08-04: 
  2020-08-05: 
  2020-08-06: 
  2020-08-07: 
  2020-08-08: 
  2020-08-09: 
  2020-08-10: 
  2020-08-11: 
  2020-08-12: 
  2020-08-13: 
  2020-08-14: 
  2020-08-15: 
  2020-08-16: 
  2020-08-17: 
  2020-08-18: 
  2020-08-19: 
  2020-08-20: 
  2020-08-21: 
  2020-08-22: 
  2020-08-23: 
  2020-08-24: 
  2020-08-25: 
  2020-08-26: 
  2020-08-27: 
  2020-08-28: 
  2020-08-29: 
  2020-08-30: 
Previous month: 2020-07, next month: 2020-09
```

If you want browser version just pass the `YYYY-MM` argument via link parameter.
If you want to exclude departure date from calendar modify the query `departureDate > :date`

Comment: Obviously responding a bit late ha! I found a different solution when developing that app and never checked back here, but was just looking through my questions and noticed you put in a lot of effort here, and felt you deserved the rep. Thanks!